# C program- find the lowest student score above, and the highest score below the boundary

Tags: c

I am finishing a program where I read in a bunch of non-negative doubles into an array, then calculate the mean and stand dev of the values. Then the mean plus the stand dev represents **getting a B**.
I am having trouble with the next part, where I need to find the **lowest score** from the array of numbers that will give me a B, and then the **highest value** in the array that did **not get a B**. I am having so much trouble with this part that any help would be amazing.
I also have to make the program stop when `EOF` is typed into it, but I can not figure that part out either, so any help with that would also be appreciated. For now I instead just made it work for all positive values and stop when a negative value is introduced, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
    int arr[100];
    int y, x;
    int i;
    double mean = 0;
    double std = 0;
    double this = 0;
    i = 0;

    printf("Enter next number, EOF to stop > ") ;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    while (x >= 0) {
        arr[i++] = x;
        printf ("Enter next number, EOF to stop > " );
        scanf("%d",&x);
    }

    y = i;

    double sum = 0;
    double sum1= 0;

    for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    mean = sum / y;

    for (i = 0; i < y; i++){
        sum1 = sum1 + pow((arr[i] - mean), 2);
    }

    std = sum1 / ((float)y - 1);

    this = mean + sqrt(std);

    if (10 > y) {
        printf("**You must enter atleast 10 scores***\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Mean = %.2lf, Standard Deviation = %.2lf\n", mean, sqrt(std));
    printf("Scores above %.2lf get a B\n", this);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, do not read in the input using `fscan(%d, &x)`, rather create a character array (for example, `char [] str = new char[5];`) and scan that with `fscan(%s, &str)`. Then, compare the string to another string containing "EOF" using `if (strcmp(str, eofStr) == 0) break`. Use atoi to convert the string to an integer.

To find the lowest score with a B, store an integer that saves the lowest number with a B. Set the initial value to the A grade value. Iterate through the loop and compare to a score for each iteration. If the score is lower, but still a B, exchange the current lowest score with this score. Finish the loop and you will have the lowest score with a B. You can do the same thing to get the highest score without a B.

```
int low = this + sqrt(std);
for (int i = 0; arr[i] > 0; i++) {
    if (low > arr[i] && arr[i] >= this) low = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: do you have an example i can reference while i write out my code for the lowest and highest score part? that would be a lot of help

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
    int arr[100];
    int y, x;
    int i;
    double mean = 0;
    double std = 0;
    double margin = 0;
    i = 0;

    printf("Enter next number, EOF to stop > ") ;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    while (x >= 0) {
        arr[i++] = x;
        printf ("Enter next number, EOF to stop > " );
        scanf("%d",&x);
    }

    y = i;
    if (10 > y) {
        printf("**You must enter atleast 10 scores***\n");
        return 0;
    }

    double sum = 0;
    double sum1= 0;

    for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    mean = sum / y;

    for (i = 0; i < y; i++){
        sum1 = sum1 + pow((arr[i] - mean), 2);
    }

    std = sum1 / ((float)y - 1.0);

    margin = mean + sqrt(std);


    printf("Mean = %.2lf, Standard Deviation = %.2lf\n", mean, sqrt(std));
    printf("Scores above %.2lf get a B\n", margin);

    int below = arr[0]; // highest value in the array that will not get a B
    int above = arr[0]; // lowest value in the array that will give a B

    for (i=0; i<y; i++) {
        if ((arr[i] > below) && (arr[i] < margin)) {
            below = arr[i];
        }
        else if ((arr[i] > margin) && (arr[i] < above)) {
            above = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you intend to program in -ansi -pedantic C, all variables must be defined at the top of the block. e.g:

Correct: 
func() {

```
variable v1;
variable v2;

perform_stuff();
```

}

In correct:
func() {

```
perform_stuff()

variable v1;
```

}

and now to your question:
if you wish to hold an array of double values, the array should be of type double and not of the type - int.

to find the lowest number in the array:
There are few possible options for that one, first, you could ask the user to enter the values from lowest to highest and then just reach to the array[0] (first location = lowest value). but if you do not/ can not, always use **quicksort**: http://www.cquestions.com/2008/01/c-program-for-quick-sort.html
to sort the array from lowest values to the highest and then find the value you wish using a **binary search**: http://www.cquestions.com/2008/01/c-program-for-binary-search.html
to search for the value you wish to.

or you could also make it work this way in the efficiency of O(N):

int heighest_smaller_than_mean = 0;

int smallest_smaller_than_mean = mean;

for(i = 0; i < mean; i++) {

```
if(heighest_smaller_than_mean < arr[i])
heighest_smaller_than_mean = arr[i];

if(smallest_smaller_than_mean < arr[i])
smallest_smaller_than_mean = arr[i];
```

}

Hope I understand you correctly :)